# When does ast.fix_missing_locations change the tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to find an example where a `visit` by a `NodeTransformer` inheritor will differ from a `visit` by a `NodeTransformer` inheritor **and** using `fix_missing_locations` on the tree.

Here's an example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) (which for some reason does not work, i.e. the tree does not change, depending on whether we apply `fix_missing_locations` or not):

```
from ast import *


class RewriteName(NodeTransformer):

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return Subscript(
            value=Name(id='data', ctx=Load()),
            slice=Constant(value=node.id),
            ctx=node.ctx
        )


tree = parse('foo', mode='eval')
new_tree = fix_missing_locations(RewriteName().visit(tree))
new_uncorrected_tree = RewriteName().visit(tree)

new_tree_str = dump(new_tree, include_attributes=True)
new_uncorrected_tree_str = dump(new_uncorrected_tree, include_attributes=True)

print(new_tree_str == new_uncorrected_tree_str)  # True
```

Comment: [When I try it](https://ideone.com/DL5vbT), the `dump(new_tree, include_attributes=True)` call fails with an AttributeError due to missing line numbers.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Everything works for me locally up to version 3.6 (3.9-3.7), and only on it the same error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above code is as follows:

```py
...

tree = parse('foo', mode='eval')
new_uncorrected_tree = RewriteName().visit(tree)
new_uncorrected_tree2 = RewriteName().visit(tree)
new_tree = fix_missing_locations(new_uncorrected_tree2)

print(
    tree is new_uncorrected_tree,   # True
    tree is new_uncorrected_tree2,  # True
    tree is new_tree)               # True
```

`tree`, `new_uncorrected_tree1`, `new_uncorrected_tree2`, and `new_tree` are the same object, therefore, they are equal and all operations with them (such as creating a string representation) will produce the same result.

If we use different objects initially, then the result will be two completely different strings:

```py
...

tree1 = parse('foo', mode='eval')
tree2 = parse('foo', mode='eval')
new_tree = fix_missing_locations(RewriteName().visit(tree1))
new_uncorrected_tree = RewriteName().visit(tree2)

print(tree1 is tree2)  # False

new_tree_str = dump(new_tree, include_attributes=True)
new_uncorrected_tree_str = dump(new_uncorrected_tree, include_attributes=True)

print(dump(new_tree) == dump(new_uncorrected_tree))  # True
print(new_tree_str == new_uncorrected_tree_str)      # False
```

`print(tree1 is tree2)` - Since `tree1` and `tree2` are different objects, `new_tree` and `new_uncorrected_tree` are also different objects.

`print(dump(new_tree) == dump(new_uncorrected_tree))` - Although the string representation (and most likely the value) of these objects are the same.

`print(new_tree_str == new_uncorrected_tree_str)` - And it is here that we can see that the `RewriteName` did not fill in attributes in `new_uncorrected_tree`, while `fix_missing_locations` did it, which is why we see the difference.

We can see the difference even more clearly if we print out the trees:

```py
print(dump(new_tree, include_attributes=True, indent=4))
print(dump(new_uncorrected_tree, include_attributes=True, indent=4))
```

```
Expression(
    body=Subscript(
        value=Name(
            id='data',
            ctx=Load(),
            lineno=1,
            col_offset=0,
            end_lineno=1,
            end_col_offset=0),
        slice=Constant(
            value='foo',
            lineno=1,
            col_offset=0,
            end_lineno=1,
            end_col_offset=0),
        ctx=Load(),
        lineno=1,
        col_offset=0,
        end_lineno=1,
        end_col_offset=0))
Expression(
    body=Subscript(
        value=Name(id='data', ctx=Load()),
        slice=Constant(value='foo'),
        ctx=Load()))
```

But we can also get such a result simply by creating an object of the same type from the same values:

```py
class RewriteName(NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return Name(node.id, node.ctx)
```

This is because when creating the node object, we did not specify all of its attributes, which is exactly what happens in the `parse` function.